# Hosta-devouring weeds

Tags: identification

A hosta in my yard has been overrun and, apparently, devoured by a weed. What is it?

[image]

Comment: Where are you located? Dominating bad weeds can vary between continents...

Comment: Northeastern US.

Comment: Please take an up close picture of the weeds.  At this distance it is impossible to make out the pure shape of the leaf and the veining in the leaf.   Colin might be correct, but I can't tell at this distance.

Answer (score 1):

This looks rather like a takeover by Jewelweed, Impatiens capensis. Shortly if you let them grow they will flower and produce touch-me-not seed capsules that will spray weed seeds all over the place. To check this identification, take a single leaf and hold it under water and the colour of the leaf may change to a silver jewelled appearance. If not then my id is wrong.

The reasoning is this - jewelweed likes constantly wet soil. Hosta likes moist but well drained soil. For this reason your hosta is drowning and looking quite sick, but the jewelweed is perky and happy where it has been able to germinate. Something is keeping that soil wet all the time. That might be an issue you need to investigate if it is close to a building.

If the soil there is naturally and for good reason constantly wet then move the hosta to a place where it will be moderately shaded, moist but well drained. Let the jewelweed do what it likes there, the kids will love playing with the seed heads when they come, and your problem wet patch will be covered in green for most of the summer. Then again if you don't like it there, it is really easy to pull when young, but you will need to ask another question as to what to plant in a wet wet wet location.